# Is there a way to hide the legend for totally null series in the Grafana panel?

Tags: time-series, grafana

**What Grafana version and what operating system are you using?**

- Grafana version: Grafana v9.3.6 (978237e7cb)
- Operating system: Windows
- Browser: Chrome

**What are you trying to achieve?**
I query a database and each column that is returned is an item in the legend. All data is grouped by a name attribute (that’s why the names are repeated in the legend). However, data represented by blue, yellow, and red colors may return null.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOySI.png)

When the series of these data is null, I would like their legend not to be displayed and that they also not appear in the tooltip.

Information to take into consideration: the name of the legends is the same as I need all the series that have the same name to be displayed when clicking to filter in the legend. For example, assuming there is no null data, if I click on any AAA legend, all AAA series should be on the chart. Like the following picture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9npKJ.png)

**What I've tried so far?**
Reading documentation and forums. But I didn’t find any solution unfortunately.

I’ve also tried adding a hidden override property to the blue AAA legend, for example. I added a new override, selected “Fields with name” and selected AAA. Then I added a property “Series > Hide in area” and marked “legend”. However, in this case, the filter by legend stopped working as I described earlier.

**Help please!**
Does anyone know how I can hide the legend and tooltip data when the series is totally null?